# inserting row at bottom in uitableview swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, insert

I'm trying to insert a row in the bottom when user scrolls to bottom of the `UITableView`. But the problem is, it is inserting the row at the bottom but it takes me back to the first row. How can i stop this from happening? here is my code

```
        func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
            dispatch_after(
                dispatch_time(
                    DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                    Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
                ),
                dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
        }

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        var tableView:UITableView = UITableView()
        var array:NSMutableArray = ["hey \n2 \n2 \n2 \n2 \n2 \n2","fjcjscsoomc   sample text message big","and this is a small text "]




        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, phonewidth, self.view.frame.height)
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
            self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            self.view.addSubview(tableView)

self.tableView.addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler { () -> Void in
                delay(2.0, { () -> () in

                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.array.insertObject("123", atIndex: self.array.count)
                    var nspath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.array.count - 1, inSection: 0)
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([nspath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()
                    self.tableView.infiniteScrollingView.stopAnimating()
                })
            }
        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


                let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CustomCell
                cell.labelText.text = array.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
                return cell

        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return array.count
            }

    }
```

this code is working fine, it inserts a row at bottom when i scroll down to bottom but after inserting tableView takes me back to the first row.

Comment: You're not calling `reloadData` anywhere are you? That's generally what results in moving back to the top of the table. Usually `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` alone would not cause that behavior.

Comment: nah not using reloadData

Comment: Well, you're doing something somewhere else to get this behavior. I just empirically confirmed that the code in your question will _not_ take you back to the first row.

Comment: @Rob i added the full code, what you think now?

Comment: You're sure you don't have an observer on self.array that calls reloadData()

Comment: I'd try pulling out your code that inserts the row (but keep the rest of your infinite scroller code) and see if the behavior is truly your inserting of the new row, or something completely different, something buried in that infinite scroller class. But try your code outside of that context and I think you'll see it's not the row inserting code, itself, that is causing the problem. BTW, you might want to consider using `[weak self]` construct in your block to avoid strong reference cycle.

Comment: i added the full viewController code

Comment: tried [weak self] still no luck

Comment: I tried removing that ** func delay** and adding dispatch function within the infitinite scroller closure, still doesn't work and most of the times im getting **constrains error** i hope it doesn't have anything to do with it,

Comment: BTW, the `[weak self]` was not to solve this problem you raised in your question, but a completely separate problem of a strong reference cycle.

Comment: https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh/blob/master/Demo/SVPullToRefreshDemo/SVViewController.m this is what I'm using in swift

Comment: I used the above code in conjunction with `UIScrollView+SVInfiniteScrolling.m`, and it worked precisely as advertised. I get spinner for 2 seconds, and then the new row shows up and it does not take me back to the first row. Are you doing anything in `CustomCell` class? I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: not doing anything in customcell, still stuck on this